# Excel VBA create a new workbook from 2 sheets in the old (+number as values not formulas)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 5 sheets: A,B,C,D,E. Sheet A has cells where there are formulae (calculation of values from B and C sheets). Additionally, sheet A has a hyperlinks to sheet D. There is also conditional formatting and number rounding (in one cell 0 decimals , in others 2).

I want to create a new workbook, where only sheets A and D are included in this new workbook. Sheets B and C should not be included in the file so in sheet A numbers should be as values but preserve hyperlinks and conditional formatting/rounding formatting. I found the following VBA code, however it does not preserve conditional formatting and hyperlinks. I do not know why, but when I use copy paste as values in a macro using different methods, not all values are pasted as values. Only using this code I have nice values preserving the formats

```
Sheets("A").Cells.Copy 
Sheets("A").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="path X.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

However, this code changes and renames my current workbook, while I need to create a new workbook with deleted sheets.
What should I change in it?

Comment: If you have a mix of values, hyperlinks and formatting on sheet A then you'll need to specify the ranges for these. You can't copy and paste the whole of sheet A and expect Excel to know to keep values for some things and not others without telling it which?

Comment: @jamheadart I tried this copy paste of the whole sheet and it is working. however, I do not know how to do the next steps:1)this change is only applicable to the new workbook and 2) only 2 sheets are in this final workbook. As I need initial workbook as it was, it is better not to do changes in it.

Comment: Use `Worksheet.Copy` to only move sheets `A` and `D` to the new workbook.

Comment: @BigBen Yes. However sheet A has formulas, which when I copy paste to new workbook will be deleted so here I guess should be created a temporary workbook and the saved as

Comment: "when I copy paste to new workbook will be deleted" ... not sure I follow.... in any case, it does feel a little bit like you are asking for the code, instead of taking a stab at it yourself.

Comment: @BigBen I have thoughts how to do it, however due to lack of experience cannot fully